# How can I get embed resource without defining serializer in Django REST Framework?

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

As I know, if I want to get an embed resource, need to define it in the proper serializer. Then it will be always embed no matter I need it or not.
If I want two different embedding propurse, I need two urls for each.

So I wonder if I could implement an `?embedded=` request like [Eve](http://python-eve.org/features.html#embedded-resource-serialization) do:
`GET (/emails/<id>/?embedded={"author":1}`, embedded resource is READ ONLY by default.

Comment: I don't think there is a inbuilt functionality for this. But you should be able to implement this quite easily. This might be a good starting point: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dynamically-modifying-fields

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to have different objects as embedded, you can implement such think with something like following:

You can pass your `kwargs` to a serializer as `context`

```
serializer = YourSerializer(data=initial_first_shop_data,
                            context={"author": 1})
```

And then override `.to_representation()` method

```
def to_representation(self, instance):
    representation = super(DynamicFieldsModelSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)

    if 'author' in self.context:
        author = AuthorSerializer(Author.objects.get(pk=self.context['author']))
        representation['author'] = author.data

    return representation
```

If you will always have `author` as embedded object, it's simpler to add it to your serializer and take it our in case if it's not in the `context`.

Comment: `author` is not the only field needing to auto-include, it's only an example, but this answer is near enough.

Comment: on the other hand, I need to config this on the server side not automated set on the browser side?

Comment: @kxxoling, If you will implement this not on the server side, you will have plenty of security issues.

Comment: I don't think so. What I want to do is defining all the related fields ready by default, but not fetched unless it's set `embedded=True` in serializer field or `embedded={"field":1}` in the request. The security part has no difference between get all related fields by default, but  would have an performance improvement.

Comment: @kxxoling, this way you will be fine, true.